# Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\x94G\xAE \xA7\xEF...' for column 'NAME' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, mysql-workbench

I am trying to figure out how to encode a column in a table. I created a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

and inserted some data into it:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (NAME)
VALUES ('USER 1'), ('USER 2'), ('USER 3');
```

Now I am trying to insert one more row, but with encrypted data:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (NAME)
VALUES(AES_ENCRYPT('USER 4','PASSWORD'));
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\x94G\xAE \xA7\xEF...' for column 'NAME' at row 1
```

From everything I read so far I found out that the problem might be in encoding. However, my checking script

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "AIRPORT";
```

showed me this: `utf8mb4`

What should I do?

Comment: Use an appropriate data type for the column. [`varbinary`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) could be what you're looking for if you want AES encrypted data in there.

Comment: It worked! Thank you @stickybit so much! I'm just wondering, why didn't it work before? In all the examples I saw `varchar` was used

Comment: utf8mb4 is a relatively new charset in MySQL. The example probably was written for an older MySQL version and you are using a more recent one.